# 400{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_ERROR","message":"Json request malformed

Tags: php, paypal

This is my connection to the database plus `$apiContext`

```
// Bootstrap and Configure
define('DB_HOST', '*');
define('DB_USERNAME', '*');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', '*');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

include __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

// Replace these values by entering your own ClientId and Secret by visiting https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps
$clientId = '*';
$clientSecret = '*';

$apiContext = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        $clientId,
        $clientSecret
    )
);

$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'log.LogEnabled' == true,
        'log.FileName' == 'PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' == 'DEBUG', // PLEASE USE `INFO` LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
        'cache.enabled' == true,
    )
);
```

This is how am creating batch payouts and testing from the sandbox.

```
if(!$mysqli){
  die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE Channel ='paypal' AND status='2' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 500";

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// # Create Bulk Payout 
use PayPal\Api\Payout;
use PayPal\Api\Currency;
use PayPal\Api\PayoutItem;
use PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader;

// Create a new instance of Payout object
$payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();

$senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
$senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
                          ->setEmailSubject("You Have a new Payment");
$payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader);
  // #### Sender Item

$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $senderItem[$i] = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
  $senderItem[$i]->setRecipientType('Email')
                 ->setReceiver($row['them_email'])
                 ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency("{ \"value\":\"{$row['tasker_amount']}\", \"currency\":\"USD\" }"))
                 ->setSenderItemId($row['created_at'])
                 ->setNote($row['pay_type']);
  $i++;
  $payouts->addItem($senderItem);
};
var_dump($senderItem);

  // ### Create Payout
try {
  $payouts->create(null, $apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
  echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
  die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  die($ex);
}
```

---

This is the error code plus the exceptions

```
400{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_ERROR","message":"Json request malformed.","debug_id":"15e4b40545d51","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors"}

PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paypal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:202 Stack trace: 
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paypal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(73): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"sender_batch_...') 
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paypal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(104): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"sender_batch_...', Array) #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paypal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payout.php(121): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"sender_batch_...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), Object(PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall)) 
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paypal-PHP-SDK/wunipayout.php(45): PayPal\Api\Payout->create(Array, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4 {main}
```

---

This is the output from var_dump($senderItem)

```
array(43) 
{ 
    [0]=> object(PayPal\Api\PayoutItem)#10 (1) 
    { 
        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(5) 
        { 
            ["recipient_type"]=> string(5) "Email" 
            ["receiver"]=> string(14) "jill@gmail.com" 
            ["amount"]=> object(PayPal\Api\Currency)#11 (1) 
            { 
                ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(2) 
                { 
                    ["value"]=> string(5) "12580" 
                    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                } 
            } 
            ["sender_item_id"]=> string(19) "2017-03-11 20:02:40" 
            ["note"]=> string(7) "TASK_ME" 
        } 
    } 

    [1]=> object(PayPal\Api\PayoutItem)#12 (1) 
    { 
        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(5)
        {
            ["recipient_type"]=> string(5) "Email" 
            ["receiver"]=> string(12) "me@gmail.com" 
            ["amount"]=> object(PayPal\Api\Currency)#13 (1) 
            { 
                ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(2) 
                { 
                    ["value"]=> string(4) "1000" 
                    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                } 
            } 
            ["sender_item_id"]=> string(19) "2017-03-09 21:41:49" 
            ["note"]=> string(4) "TASK" 
        } 
    } 

    [2]=> object(PayPal\Api\PayoutItem)#14 (1) 
    { 
        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(5) 
        { 
            ["recipient_type"]=> string(5) "Email" 
            ["receiver"]=> string(12) "me@gmail.com" 
            ["amount"]=> object(PayPal\Api\Currency)#15 (1) 
            { 
                ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(2) 
                { 
                    ["value"]=> string(4) "1288" 
                    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                } 
            } 
            ["sender_item_id"]=> string(19) "2017-03-06 18:04:47" 
            ["note"]=> string(4) "TASK" 
        } 
    }

    [3]=> object(PayPal\Api\PayoutItem)#16 (1) 
    { 
        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(5) 
        { 
            ["recipient_type"]=> string(5) "Email" 
            ["receiver"]=> string(13) "tex@gmail.com" 
            ["amount"]=> object(PayPal\Api\Currency)#17 (1) 
            { 
                ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(2) 
                { 
                    ["value"]=> string(1) "3" 
                    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                } 
            } 
            ["sender_item_id"]=> string(19) "2017-03-05 22:41:56" 
            ["note"]=> string(7) "PROJECT" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Help me figure out why am getting this error am new to the PayPal Payouts API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be forming your own JSON string and passing it.

Instead, create an object using `stdClass` and assign properties and values to it. Then, use `json_encode` to pass to PayPal.

For example (excerpt, untested):

```
// Create empty object
$payAmount = new stdClass;

// Assign object attributes
$payAmount->value = $row['tasker_amount'];
$payAmount->currency = "USD";

// Create currency object
$currency = new \PayPal\Api\Currency(
  json_encode($payAmount)
);

$senderItem[$i]->setRecipientType('Email')
  ->setReceiver($row['email'])
  ->setAmount($currency)
  ->setSenderItemId($row['created_at'])
  ->setNote($row['pay_type']);
```

I believe the issue comes from when you're calling the `addItem` method. This may solve your problem (use this entire loop). This also uses the modifications above:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Create empty object
    $payAmount = new stdClass;

    // Assign object attributes
    $payAmount->value = $row['tasker_amount'];
    $payAmount->currency = "USD";

    // Create currency object
    $currency = new \PayPal\Api\Currency(
       json_encode($payAmount)
    );

    $senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
    $senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
                 ->setReceiver($row['them_email'])
                 ->setAmount($currency)
                 ->setSenderItemId($row['created_at'])
                 ->setNote($row['pay_type']);

    $payouts->addItem($senderItem);
};
```

Notice that I dropped `$i`, as it's useless in this case. You are appending the item in each iteration, so counting the item doesn't matter.

One last edit I could throw in here... Instead of creating a `stdClass` and `json_encode`ing it, you could use the methods that the `Currency` class has in the Paypal SDK:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Currency();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD");
    $amount->setValue((float)$row['tasker_amount']); // float values only

    $senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
    $senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
                 ->setReceiver($row['them_email'])
                 ->setAmount($amount)
                 ->setSenderItemId($row['created_at'])
                 ->setNote($row['pay_type']);

    $payouts->addItem($senderItem);
};
```

Comment: Looking a little closely at your source, I don't see where `$apiContext` is defined. Have you removed some lines from the source you pasted?

Comment: Yes I have removed some lines

Comment: How would you go about creating one for `->setReceiver($row['email'])` ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, sorry. You need to post as much source as possible for us to be able to help. Are you sure that the posted section you had provided is the issue?

Comment: I have included the `$apiContext`

Comment: @ElvisMwenda I believe I have found the issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: Updated once more.

Comment: sure this works but the it's creating only a single payout